# How do I write a single front-end application to accommodate a shared database/seperate schema data structure?

Tags: database-design, frontend, database-schema, multi-tenant, web-frontend

I'm creating a SaaS application using django rest framework and the django-tenant-schemas package with a postgresql database. Each user in the database has the same base schema. The user can extend the base schema to allow for custom tables/columns.

So If I want to write a single front-end that will be able to account for customized tables how do I do it? (I'm using angular 2 if that helps)

In order to conform to SO's policy of asking questions that can be answered and not just discussed, here are my questions:

1) Is it even possible to write a single front-end application for this type of data structure?

2)Is there a word, concept, or idea for what I'm trying to do? I'd like to be able to research this more but I'm having a hard time knowing what to even google.

If my question seems vague it's because i'm still trying to figure out how to ask it. If you need clarification don't hesitate to ask in the comments. I'm really just looking for an answer to #2 so I can continue my research.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but difficult (and no, there isn't really a word for it that I'm aware of). Your application will need to take on some of the duties of a database administration application *in addition to* its original functionality, and then the user interface needs to be able to adapt to the mutable schema. You'll be doing a lot of querying the system tables in order to discover what users are doing to their schemata, and managing access and permissions yourself in order to ensure that users can alter their changes but not the core schema.

Are you certain a relational database is what you need? It's hard to suggest anything without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, but if your model isn't too complex a 'schemaless' document database like MongoDB may be more appropriate. If you do have a highly relational structure that just needs to support customization on top, consider leveraging Postgres' JSON/JSONB data types.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this sort of setup is purely an API concern, not a frontend concern. Remember your frontend doesn't care about how your database(s) are set up - it only cares about the APIs that it can call. Your API has to do the work having common endpoints that everyone can call and then accessing the correct database based on the current user. This is called a multi-tenant application - and actually, Rails has a gem that provides this functionality [(the apartment gem)](https://github.com/influitive/apartment). I know you're using Django, but if Rails has a 'plugin' to assist with this setup, I wouldn't be surprised if Django has something similar.

Note that because different users may have different tables, your front end isn't completely static - it may actually have to include API requests that return user-customised information to help it configure its UI based on the different users' needs. It's not a sticking point - just something to include in your front end application design.

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your database design. The way you are going will result in lots of maintenance issues down the line.

Here's a great whitepaper by Microsoft on [data architecture for SaaS applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx).

And here's an [article on Salesforce architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture).

For your specific case, say you have a contacts table where users store their contacts. You could have a common base table with common fields that all tenants/accounts will have. Then have a contact_custom_fields table to store custom field definitions. This table may have fieldId, accountId, fieldName, fieldType...

Lastly have a contact_custom_field_values table to store actual field values for the custom fields. This table can have accountId, contactId, fieldId, fieldValue.